# How do I map through group of two or more Arrays to get a length result?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

[image]I have two or more Arrays with inputs

```
this.listNumber = [
  {
    "GenericQuestions": [
      {
          "input": "long",
      },
      {
          "input": "dog",
      },
      {
          "input": "",
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    "GenericQuestions": [
      {
          "input": "fred",
      },
      {
          "input": "barney",
      },
      {
          "input": "betty",
      }
    ]
  }
]

// can be more Arrays
```

I have previously used this getFilter Method to get the results of inputs with values from a single Array

```
getFilter(index: string | number) {  // index being 0
    return this.listNumber[index].GenericQuestions.filter((c: { input: any }) => !!c.input).length;
} // returns 2
```

What I am trying to figure out is how I would get results of inputs filled out from both Arrays.

I even tried

```
  const flatfile = this.listNumber.flat();
  console.log("flatfile", flatfile);
```

But I think it failed because GenericQuestions are inside separate objects.

Comment: Please provide valid objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your array `listNumbers` looks like this:

```js
this.listNumbers = [
    {
        "GenericQuestions": [
            {
                "input": "some text 1"
            },
            {
                "input": "some text 2"
            },  
            {
                "input": "some text 3"
            } 
        ]
    },
    {
        "GenericQuestions": [
            {
                "input": "some text 4"
            },
            {
                "input": "some text 5"
            },  
            {
                "input": "some text 6"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

To get the input fields from both arrays (`"GenericQuestions"`), you may create a new array and fill it with the elements of all `"GenericQuestions"` arrays

```js
const newArray = []

for (let object of this.listNumbers) {
    newArray.push(...object["GenericQuestions"])
}
```

This will give you a flat array, containing all input objects

```js
newArray = [
    {
        "input": "some text 1"
    },
    {
        "input": "some text 2"
    },
    {
        "input": "some text 3"
    },
    {
        "input": "some text 4"
    },
    {
        "input": "some text 5"
    },
    {
        "input": "some text 6"
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks worked great.  I came up with a solution of looping the generic question and child arrays, but your solution is much more elegant.

Comment: Great, that I was able to help you

Comment: @ThomasDegroot Please consider giving me the bounty ^^ Thanks

Comment: you got it,  had to wait 5 hours before awarding it

Answer (score 1):

if I get you right. The code below is solution

```
let listNumber = [{
    GenericQuestion: [{ input: "long" }, { input: "dog"}, { input: ""}]
}, 
{
    GenericQuestion: [ {input: "fred"}, { input: "barney"}, { input: "betty" } ]
}];

let result = listNumber.map(x => x.GenericQuestion).flat().filter(t=>!!t.input);

console.log(result);
```

output:

```
[
  { input: 'long' },
  { input: 'dog' },
  { input: 'fred' },
  { input: 'barney' },
  { input: 'betty' }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you just need to sum up number of non-empty `input`s from your `listNumber` array. Right?

Then all you need to do is... well... sum up:

```js
let total_cnt = 0
for( let i = 0 ; i !== this.listNumber.length ; ++i ) total_cnt += this.getFilter(i)
console.log(total_cnt)
```

or if you prefer functional style:

```js
const total_cnt = this.listNumber.reduce((total_cnt, _, i) => total_cnt + this.getFilter(i), 0)
```

No need to create temporary arrays, or to rewrite already tested logic of `getFilter`. DRY!